# Css animation not running after first run

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs one for expanding content and one for heading text.
I expand them by changing a class on the parent element (via javascript) and then setting `height/width` to `0` and `visibility` to `hidden`

I'm trying to figure out why the css animation stops running after the first expansion and how to make the timing consistent.
I'm using `max-height` for the animation because I don't know the target height.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aJ3SN/)

```
[data-element] {
    transition: max-height 4s ease;
}
.collapsed [data-element="collapsed"] {
    max-height: 900px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: It's even weirder, because when I focus out of the window, and then refocus, the css animation works for me. I'm guessing it's some bug related to when `max-height` forces the real `height` calculations.

Comment: I think it is involved the [*reversing of the interrupted transition*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#reversing), since if you wait at least four seconds between each click it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got something working here, but the animation with max-height causes a delay, making this not an ideal solution.

removing some of this helped

```
height:auto;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XXRWx/1/